# Using JBoss ESB, how do I get multiple objects out of smooks and use them as params to an ejb?

Tags: java, jboss, esb, smooks

This is part of my jboss-esb.xml file:

```
<action name="HotelAvailRq_To_HotelAvailRequest" class="org.jboss.soa.esb.smooks.SmooksAction">
  <property name="smooksConfig" 
            value="requestConverters/HotelAvailRq_To_HotelAvailRequest.xml" />
  <property name="resultType" 
           value="JAVA" />
  <!-- <property name="javaResultBeanId" value="hotel" /> --> 
  <!-- <property name="set-payload-location" value="map" /> -->                 
  <property name="mappedContextObjects" 
            value="hotel,dateRange" />
  <property name="reportPath"
    value="C:\Documents and Settings\barrowj\esb-workspace\esb\smooks-in-report.html" />
</action>
<action name="print-result" class="org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.SystemPrintln" >
  <property name="message" value="Read" />
  <property name="printfull" value="true" />
</action>
<action name="availabilityCall" 
        class="org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.EJBProcessor">
  <property name="ejb3" value="true" />
  <property name="jndi-name" value="HotelBooking/remote" />
  <property name="initial-context-factory" 
            value="org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" />
  <property name="provider-url" value="jnp://localhost:1099" />
  <property name="method" value="availability" />                   
  <property name="ejb-params">
    <arg0 type="model.domain.Hotel">map.hotel</arg0>
    <arg1 type="model.domain.value_objects.DateRange">body.map.dateRange</arg1>
    <arg2 type="model.domain.value_objects.RoomRequest">roomRequest</arg2>
    <arg3 type="model.domain.RatePlanList">ratePlanList</arg3>
    <arg4 type="model.domain.AmenityList">amenityList</arg4>
    <arg5 type="model.domain.types.Money">minimumRate</arg5>
    <arg6 type="model.domain.types.Money">maximumRate</arg6>
    <arg7 type="model.domain.Partner">partner</arg7>
  </property>
</action>
```

The smooks call returns

```
body: [ objects: 
  {org.jboss.soa.esb.message.defaultEntry=
    { dateRange=DateRange [  thru=2010-03-24, from=2010-03-23], 
      roomRequest=RoomRequest [list=[GuestInfo [count=1, age=null]], numberOfRooms=1],
      PTIME=null, 
      guestInfo=GuestInfo [count=1, age=null], 
      PUUID=null, 
      partner=Partner [partnerId=bukuser], 
      hotel=Hotel [id=61044, name=null, chainCode=BW, roomTypes=[], maxStay=P30D, bookings=[], ratePlans=[]], 
      guestInfoList=[GuestInfo [count=1, age=null]]}, 
    SmooksExecutionContext={}} ]
```

So, I need to map the dateRange, roomRequest, guestInfo and the other EJB params to the EJB call.  Is there a way to do this?

The documentation indicates you can, but doesn't say how to get a map value out of the context map in XML.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem turns out to be the interaction between the smooks action and the ejb action.  Smooks returns a hashmap of stuff.  It puts that hashmap inside the message.body of the ESB.  Which, in turn is a hashmap.

The ejb action is looking for message.getBody().get("name"), when it should be looking for message.getBody().get("smooksResults").get("name").  There is no way to tell the ejb action to look in there.

The only solution is to change the EJB action so it can look in the smooks results hashmap.